# How to aggregate on different variables from two columns in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this-

```
PatGroup     Variable       Value       StudyQuarter
A            Patientdays    100         1
B            ExposedDays    80          1
A            ExposedDays    40          1
A            Patients       40          1
C            ExposedDays    10          1
C            PatientDays    90          1
A            Patientdays    20          2
B            ExposedDays    90          2
```

and many such further combinations of variables in Columns 'PatGroup' and 'Variable'

I want a function that will let me select a combination of entries from column 'PatGroup' and a combination of entries from column 'Variable' to get the desired outputs.
For example, I want to calculate a proportion which calculates the sum of values for PatGroups A and B for variable ExposedDays as Numerator; and PatGroups A, B and C for variables ExposedDays and PatientDays as Denominator.

The output would look like-

```
Numerator  Denominator  Proportion   StudyQaurter   NewPatGroup   Measure
120        320           0.37        1              A&B/A&B&C     ExposedDays/PatientDays
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Could you please provide a *specific example* including expected output for the sample data you give. I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. It sounds like `aggregate` will be your friend.

Comment: ???? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49941145/edit) your original question, and include your expected output (I assume it's a `data.frame`) for the sample data you give!

Comment: I have amended the question now

Comment: Not clear. The sum of `Value` for `Variable == "ExposedDays"` and (`PatGroups == A` or `PatGroups == B`) is `80 + 40 + 90 = 210`. Why is `Numerator=120`? Similarly, why is `Denominator=320` and not `80 + 40 + 10 + 90 = 220`? Why is `StudyQuarter=1` in your expected output?

Comment: Because I need to group the outputs by Study Quarters. I have given an example for one quarter here but I need this to be done across 30 odd quarters. So for quarter 1, Variable == "ExposedDays" and PatGroup==A or PatGroup==B)  and StudyQuarter ==1 is 80+40=120

Comment: **You don't mention grouping by `StudyQuarters` anywhere in your original post!** If I hadn't asked you to clarify, how do you expect us to infer such critical information from your post? I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. From what I understand, manipulating/summarising data in such a way sounds like a bad idea. Perhaps revise your problem statement/approach?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not sure what the point is of aggregating data the way that you propose, but you can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(StudyQuarter) %>%
    summarise(
        Numerator = sum(Value[Variable == "ExposedDays" & PatGroup %in% c("A", "B")]),
        Denominator = sum(Value[Variable %in% c("ExposedDays", "PatientDays") & PatGroup %in% c("A", "B", "C")]),
        Proportion = Numerator / Denominator,
        NewPatGroup = "A&B/A&B&C",
        Measure = "ExposedDays/PatientDays")
## A tibble: 2 x 6
#  StudyQuarter Numerator Denominator Proportion NewPatGroup Measure
#         <int>     <int>       <int>      <dbl> <chr>       <chr>
#1            1       120         320      0.375 A&B/A&B&C   ExposedDays/Patien…
#2            2        90         110      0.818 A&B/A&B&C   ExposedDays/Patien…
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "PatGroup     Variable       Value       StudyQuarter
A            PatientDays    100         1
B            ExposedDays    80          1
A            ExposedDays    40          1
A            Patients       40          1
C            ExposedDays    10          1
C            PatientDays    90          1
A            PatientDays    20          2
B            ExposedDays    90          2", header = T)
```